# SQL - Update statement in procedure - dependent filed gets filled only on second run of the procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is  my update procedure:

```
UPDATE tbl1
SET
    -- other columns
    tbl1.field_1 = CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(10), carsAll.DateOfBirth, 104)),
    tbl1.field_2 = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) - DATEPART(YEAR, tbl1.field_1),
    -- other columns
FROM 
    [db1].[cars].[table_1] AS tbl1
INNER JOIN 
    [db2].[cars].[carsAll_test] AS carsAll ON tbl1.[TP_PK]=carsAll.[TP_PK]
```

First time I run procedure all columns gets filled with data except `tbl1.field_2`.

Second time I run it `tbl1.field_2` gets filled as well.

How do I update all columns in one run and why is this happening when `tbl1.field_1` is set before procedure starts with `tbl1.field_2` ?

I'm using SQL Server 2017 (v14).

Comment: Have you tried computing the new field_1 value in an outer apply so that you can reference it in your field_2 expression? The tbl1.field_1 value you're referencing currently is the previous/persisted value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is this happening when tbl1.field_1 is set before procedure starts with tbl1.field_2

The field on the right side of your query (`tbl1.field_1`) will refer to its original value(before update), regardless of the order they are in.

In simple words, the updated value for `tbl1.field_1` will be available only after the whole update statement in completed. So, you can't use this line in this same update statement
`tbl1.field_2 = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) - DATEPART(YEAR, tbl1.field_1),`

> How do I update all columns in one run

Instead of referencing `tbl1.field_1`, you can directly reference `carsAll.DateOfBirth`

```
UPDATE tbl1
SET
    -- other columns
    tbl1.field_1 = CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(10), carsAll.DateOfBirth, 104)),
    tbl1.field_2 = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) - DATEPART(YEAR, carsAll.DateOfBirth),
    -- other columns
FROM 
    [db1].[cars].[table_1] AS tbl1
INNER JOIN 
    [db2].[cars].[carsAll_test] AS carsAll ON tbl1.[TP_PK]=carsAll.[TP_PK]
```